# If $(f_n)$ is a uniformly convergent sequence in $C(X)$, and $f_n\to f$ uniformly, then $\{f\} \cup \{f_n : n\ge 1\}$ is compact in $C(X)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence, uniform-continuity

> Let $X$ denote a compact metric space. If $(f_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a uniformly convergent sequence in $C(X)$, and $f_n\to f$ uniformly, then show that $\{f\} \cup \{f_n : n\ge 1\}$ is compact in $C(X)$.

I've multiple approaches in mind to prove the compactness of $S = \{f\} \cup \{f_n: n\ge 1\}$, but I haven't been able to complete any of them:

1. $S$ is compact iff every sequence in $S$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $S$.
2. $S$ is compact iff every open cover of $S$ has a finite subcover.
3. $S$ is compact iff $S$ is complete and totally bounded.

How do I approach this problem? I am not sure where to use the compactness of $X$,  and the fact that $f_n\stackrel{\text{unif}}{\longrightarrow} f$. For the second approach - I am not sure what open sets in $C(X)$ look like; so I'm not able to get anything useful by writing $S \subset \bigcup_{A\in O} A$ where $O$ is a family of open sets of $C(X)$.

Please let me know what direction to proceed in, and drop some hints - so I can find my way out of this wilderness. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any metric space $(Y,d)$ (or any topological space $Y$ for that matter) any convergent sequence $(y_n)$ with limit $y$ gives a compact set $\{y,y_1,y_2,...\}$ and this is easy to prove from definition of compactness in terms of  open covers. Take $Y=C(X)$ with the sup metric.

Comment: If a sequence $x_n \to x$, then any open set containing $x$, contains all but finitely many terms of the sequence $(x_n)$. Suppose we have an open cover of $\{x,x_1,x_2,...\}$ given by $\{O_i\}_{i\in I}$. From this open cover, find an open set that contains $x$ (we know one exists, it's a cover), and call it $O$. $O$ contains all but finitely many terms of $(x_n)$. Let the terms not contained in $O$ be given by $x_{k_1}, x_{k_2}, \ldots, x_{k_N}$. Consider open sets $O_i$, such that $x_{k_i} \in O_i$. for $1\le i\le N$.

Comment: Then, $$O \cup \bigcup_{i=1}^N O_i$$ is a finite open cover for $\{x,x_1,x_2,...\}$. Hence, the set $\{x,x_1,x_2,...\}$ is compact. Is this good?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.